# Set-Cookie was blocked from subdomain

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

the domain api.example.com is accessed over **https**, it set a cookie named 'uid', and secure flag of 'uid' default to true(browser do it).

and the subdomain m.api.example.com is accessed over **http**, it also set 'uid' cookie, and secure flag default to false.

when I first access api.example.com, then access m.api.example.com, the 'uid' cookie of m.api.example.com was blocked.

the warning in chrome (F12 -> Network -> Headers -> Set-Cookie):

> The Set-Cookie was blocked because it was not sent over a secure connection and would have overwritten a cookie with the Secure attribute.

chrome has this problem, my version is 88.0.4324.96. Firefox is ok.

the subdomain can't access **host only** cookie of parent domain, why blocked?